# R cut one row into multiple rows of equal length

Tags: r

I am trying to cut one row

x = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12]

into multiple rows of equal length so that

y(row1) = [1 2  3  4

y(row2) =  5 6  7  8

y(row3) = 9 10 11 12]

I know I can achieve this  using a combination of rbind and cbind, but the dataset I am trying to apply this to is much larger than the example, so I am looking for a way to do it more quickly and automatically. I tried cut and cut2 but those didnt work either

jelle

Comment: I have a feeling this is intended to be pseudo code, but the way you've defined x in your question is not valid R syntax. use `x <- 1:12` or `x <- seq(1,12, by = 1)` or even `x <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function `matrix()` is your friend here:

```
> matrix(1:12, nrow = 3, byrow = TRUE)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    2    3    4
[2,]    5    6    7    8
[3,]    9   10   11   12
```

Note the optional parameter, `byrow`. The default is FALSE and will fill the matrix by columns, setting it to true in this case gets the data arranged in the order that you described.Just something to be careful about, since R won't throw an error if you fill by column, but your data won't be in the right format!

Answer (score 3):

Use `matrix`:

```
> y <- 1:12
> y
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12
> matrix(y,3,4,byrow=1)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    2    3    4
[2,]    5    6    7    8
[3,]    9   10   11   12
```

**Edit:** I included the `byrow=TRUE` argument to `matrix` (pointed out by Chase in the comments)  which fills the matrix *along* the rows instead of *down* the columns.

Comment: Just an FYI, to match the OP's output, you'd need to fill by row.